# WSO2 ESB too many open files

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, wso2, wso2-esb

We have a problem in our installation of wso2 esb.

We have only 4 proxy services configured, after one month without problems we started to have the following error:

```
2013-10-02 09:29:09,366 [-] [PassThroughHTTPSListener]  WARN PassThroughHttpSSLListener System may be unstable: HTTPS ListeningIOReactor encountered a checked exception : Too many open files
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:189)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:129)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:113)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:313)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener$2.run(PassThroughHttpListener.java:180)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
```

If I list the list of files open by java, I will see hundreds of:

```
java      3906       root  150u     sock                0,7         0t0       9928 can't identify protocol
java      3906       root  151u     sock                0,7         0t0      10004 can't identify protocol
```

Someone could point me out the cause of this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the max open file limit..

```
Eg: ulimit -f 65000
```

Comment: I've already configured this value, but that only gives me more time. The error appears soon or later.

Comment: Increase the number of file handlers 
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf 
fs.file-max = 1000000 
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 1000000 

 and increase the number of files to user 
sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf 
xxx soft nofile 100000 
xxx hard nofile 100000

Comment: I think above setting should fix the issue. If you still face issue, please create an jira ticket with all your settings.

Comment: Sorry @Ratha, but I can not understand why is this going to solve my problem?Your solution only increases the number of open files that I can have, but when the ESB gets into this extrange state, it will open thousands of open files, it doesn't matter which is the limit because you will

Comment: Sorry @Ratha but I can not understand, why is this going to solve my problem? Your solution only increases the number of open files that I can have open. When the ESB gets into this extrange state it produces that the socket doesn't get closed and the number of open files start to increase. It doesn't matter which is the limit because you will exceed the limit.